# appengine randomly serves old files

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm currently using Google Appengine to host a website with `Golang` as the backend. I have a custom domain setup and (sometimes) it works perfectly fine. My website requires some css and js files from the server. These were served perfectly in the past but now it randomly stops working. Both on the "mydomain.de" and on the "myapp.appspot.com" domains. Sometimes it works on the normal domain and then it works on the other and sometimes even on both. But if I reload the site after a couple of minutes it just shows me an old index.html file (that I have removed days ago).

Did someone experience this problem in the past and does anyone know a fix for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the versions of the instances that are running, and use `curl` or similar client to ensure you have no caching in play.  Also ensure that your DNS lookups are returning the results you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ruled out your browser cache as the source of the problem? If after getting a stale version, shift-reload (assuming Chrome or Firefox) brings up the desired version, then look into how to do "cache busting" for css and js, and check the `app.yaml` doc for how to set expiration times on static assets (assuming your `index.html` is static).

Comment: Since I need the `go` backend to fetch new data from a database and put these onto the page, the `index` html file is a go htmltemplate. I think I ruled out caching on the localmachine & browser, since I tried to use different devices (phone, tablet, laptop, etc..) and different browsers on these devices and all gave me random older html template files from the project.

Comment: The next bigger stick is to update the `version:` in `app.yaml`. If you don't, there's a small possibility that you have instances with the old code serving requests.

Comment: I think i resolved the error to being some kind of server side caching thing. As the `expires` date in the header says that it expires in 5 days and the return status code is either 204 or 304. So I think its a caching thing on googles server. Do you know any fix to this by chance? Otherwise I'll just wait the five days and hope that its resolved by then. Thanks for your help sofar :)